# multiple Gateways on different ports of the same istio-proxy deployment not working as expected

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

### 1. Install Istio (1.0.2)

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/knative/serving/master/third_party/istio-1.0.2/istio-crds.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/knative/serving/master/third_party/istio-1.0.2/istio.yaml
```

### 2. Create two `Deployment`s and their corresponding `Service`s

```sh
# Create Deployments
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-a
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: a
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: a
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: print
          image: gcr.io/invertible-lens-220304/print
          env:
          - name: TEXT_TO_PRINT
            value: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-b
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: b
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: b
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: print
          image: gcr.io/invertible-lens-220304/print
          env:
          - name: TEXT_TO_PRINT
            value: "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
EOF

# Create Services
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-a
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: a
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-b
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: b
EOF
```

### 3. Create two `Gateway`s and their corresponding NodePorts

```sh
# Create gateways
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway-a
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 3001
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway-b
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 3002
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
EOF

# Add ports to the istio-ingressgateway service
kubectl patch service istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system --type json --patch "$(cat <<EOF
  [{
    "op" : "add" ,
    "path" : "/spec/ports/-" ,
    "value" : {
      "name" : "node-port-1",
      "nodePort" : 30001,
      "port": 3001,
      "protocol": "TCP",
      "targetPort": 3001
    }
  }, {
    "op" : "add" ,
    "path" : "/spec/ports/-" ,
    "value" : {
      "name" : "node-port-2",
      "nodePort" : 30002,
      "port": 3002,
      "protocol": "TCP",
      "targetPort": 3002
    }
  }]
EOF)"
```

### 4. Create `VirtualService`s for each `Gateway`

```sh
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: virtualservice-a
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  gateways:
    - gateway-a
  hosts:
    - example.com
  http:
    - match:
        - authority:
            exact: example.com
      route:
        - destination:
            host: service-a.default.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: virtualservice-b
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  gateways:
    - gateway-b
  hosts:
    - example.com
  http:
    - match:
        - authority:
            exact: example.com
      route:
        - destination:
            host: service-b.default.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 80
EOF
```

### 5. Test

```sh
NODE_IP=$(kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath="{.items[0].status.addresses[1].address}")

curl $NODE_IP:30001 -H "Host: example.com"
# Result: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
curl $NODE_IP:30002 -H "Host: example.com"
# Result: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

kubectl delete virtualservice virtualservice-a -n istio-system

curl $NODE_IP:30001 -H "Host: example.com"
# Result: BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
curl $NODE_IP:30002 -H "Host: example.com"
# Result: BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

---

Since `30001` is bound to `gateway-a` which has `virtualservice-a` pointing to `service-a`, and `30002` is bound to `gateway-b` which has `virtualservice-b` pointing to `service-b`, I would expected the result to be:

```sh
curl $NODE_IP:30001 -H "Host: example.com"
# Result: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
curl $NODE_IP:30002 -H "Host: example.com"
# Result: BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

What happened and how can I get it to work?

P.S.

1. I know it's possible with two `istio-ingressgateway` deployments, but can I achieve the same results with just one?
2. Another possibility is to use just one `VirtualService` and one `Gateway`, and set the `port` in `HTTPMatchRequest`, but that still is not what I want.
3. Yes I want the host names to be the same. Aren't the gateways isolated from each other?

What I want is to have two gateways on different ports of the same `istio-proxy` *(docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.0.2)* deployment, with their own corresponding sets of virtual services, without affecting one another. Is that possible?

Comment: You point service `service-a` and `service-b` to the deployments, however I can't find `containerPort` defined for the related container. Istio mesh resources(Gateway, Virtualservice) have been adjusted to work with HTTP, instead of the Deployments and related Services set with TCP protocol connection.

Comment: @mk_sta thanks for the reply, the containers listen on port 80 for HTTP traffic. I omitted the `containerPort` field indeed, but according to the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/) this field is *primarily informational* and not mandatory. The main problem here is not that of HTTP server not working, but that istio seems to be mixing up VirtualServices of two different Gateways.

Comment: How about discrepancy between TCP and HTTP protocols defined in your configuration?